# How to build libpng using CMake

Tags: cmake

I want to build libpng using CMake, but I cannot build because an error that Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses _ROOT variables has occurred when I configure CMake.

1. Download [zlib-1.2.11](https://zlib.net/) and [libpng-1.6.37](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).
2. I have written CMakeLists.txt.

```
add_subdirectory(libpng)
add_subdirectory(zlib)
```

3. Libpng in CMakeLists.txt which depends on zlib is as follows:

```
option(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB "Custom zlib Location, else find_package is used" OFF)

if(NOT PNG_BUILD_ZLIB)
  find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
  include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

Therefore I set `ZLIB_ROOT` variable to work find_package command.

```
set(ZLIB_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib)
add_subdirectory(libpng)
add_subdirectory(zlib)
```

4. `ZLIB_ROOT` is not work, because policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses _ROOT variables.
   Therefore I set cmake_policy command whitch is as follows:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
set(ZLIB_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib)
add_subdirectory(libpng)
add_subdirectory(zlib)
```

However, cmake_policy command is not work. An error which CMP0074 is not set has occured yet.

Comment: The `*_ROOT` variables are usually used with `find_package`, not while trying to build the package (i.e., what `add_subdirectory` is used for).

Comment: `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)` is used in CMakeLists.txt of libpng.

Comment: `find_package` tries to find a package that's already built and installed.  Do you have zlib installed?

Comment: Please, add **all relevant code** into the question post. *Guessing* game is not how Stack Overflow works.